# Simple MySql - Get Largest Number in Table

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I need to use the MySQL Order By function in a query except I need it to be in reverse order by number - therefore like 45, 32, 12, 10 instead of 10, 12, 32, 45. I would then limit it to 1 so I would get the highest number in the list. However if you have another way to do this that would be great thanks :D

Anyway thanks for your help!

Christian Stewart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options - using LIMIT:

```
  SELECT yt.numeric_column
    FROM YOUR_TABLE yt
ORDER BY yt.numeric_column DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Using MAX:

```
SELECT MAX(yt.numeric_column)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE yt
```

Answer (score 0):

you want: `ORDER BY numeric_column DESC`

the `DESC` reverses it. (You can then add `LIMIT` after that)